# Live upgrade with docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm making a docker image for a daemon that can be upgraded live without restarting. And I'm making it minimal by using a [multistage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) and start everything with docker-compose.

Since this daemon has most of its features in loadable modules, upgrades are usually just a matter of reloading them. Which is a very nice feature to have, because restarting the daemon would mean disconnecting all the users. But I don't know how to keep this feature with a docker image.

---

A shared volume obviously come to mind, but this doesn't seem to play well with a multistage build or with docker-compose.

Comment: What is it you want to actually _do_?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatley, I don't think this is possible with docker. As docker images are immutable, you need to create a new image with the new version of unrealircd. From that image you can start a new docker container. Using a shared volume would be possible in theory but that is really not the intended use-case of volumes. Volumes are the preferred mechanism for persisting data generated by and used by Docker containers. If you use them to store the modules of unrealircd you loose the ability to just take your docker image and start another container with the same application in it.

Comment: And how about making an image with all the modules inside a directory marked with a `VOLUME` directive? So that if a hot upgrade is needed, the said-volume could be mounted in a specific image made for upgrading the modules in the image.